# iOS apps image sizes

Tags: ios, xcode

I am in the final stages of my app and after much research I can not find an answer to my question and I dont want my app to be bounced back for a silly thing...

I've buttons that are images within my app, I've read the [apple guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) and there is nothing around a preferred size of button images within the app. Do I've to provide 2 images one in low res and another in high ress of a button background image like a "bin" that would scale perfectly to higher ress just by stretching it?

Comment: The size of your button images surely depends on the size of your buttons, but you generally would have "1x" and "2x" versions.

Comment: Given that the 3GS supports iOS 6 I would think that you'd need to supply images in both resolutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple recommends at least 44x44 points for anything that can be touched by the user on iOS. You can find that information here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Characteristics/Characteristics.html

Hope it helps! :)